# Filtering XmlNodeList with additional XPath query?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a large XML document and I am using C# to query the content. I have something similar to the following:

```
var bookA = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/books/book[yearPublished=2012 and id=123]");
var bookB = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/books/book[yearPublished=2012 and id=456]");
var bookC = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/books/book[yearPublished=2012 and id=789]");
```

As you can see, the filter on "yearPublished" is repeated in each query and, please correct me if I'm wrong, the entire list of books is parsed repeatedly. Would it be more efficient to have something like the following:

```
var newBooks = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/books/book[yearPublished=2012]");
var bookA = newBooks.SelectSingleNode("book[id=123]");
var bookB = newBooks.SelectSingleNode("book[id=456]");
var bookC = newBooks.SelectSingleNode("book[id=789]");
```

Assuming my document is large (let's say it contains the data about several thousand books), am I correct that it would be more efficient to filter the data based on the first criteria and then select the desired XmlNode from the filtered list?

Secondly, I was trying to validate my assumption but I am having trouble. I get an error message about SelectSingleNode:

> 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' does not contain a definition for
>   'SelectSingleNode' and no extension method 'SelectSingleNode'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a reference to System.Xml and also "using System.Xml". Am I missing something else?

Comment: The XML is "already parsed" when `xmlDoc` is used. Only the XPath query has to be [re]evaluated. Yes, multiple times means "more work", but it doesn't mean "practically slower" and it might be just as fast -- or faster! -- than iterating, because of the ID clause. The only way to know of certain is to benchmark.

Comment: Personally, I prefer XDocument/[XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement_members(v=vs.90).aspx) and friends as it supports XPath via extension methods. Is it faster? I do not know or care as I like the interface better, it looks cleaner to me, and I have no such performance considerations :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) method returns an [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) type. The method [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) belongs to the [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxz4hfh3.aspx) class.

You can get your books like this:

```
var bookA = newBooks.Where(x => x.Attributes["id"].Value == 123);
var bookB = newBooks.Where(x => x.Attributes["id"].Value == 456);
var bookC = newBooks.Where(x => x.Attributes["id"].Value == 789);
```

Comment: Although this might be "slower" (fsvo, in some degenerate cases) than the three separate queries because the selector cannot take advantage of the `ID` in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newBooks = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/books/book[yearPublished=2012]");
```

This will return a [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) object.  This object does not contain a method called `SelectSingleNode`, which is why the compiler is telling you that.

You can iterate over nodes in the `XmlNodeList` returned from the `SelectNodes` method like so:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in newBooks)
{
   //...
}
```

As for your performance issue, or perceived performance issue, I suggest you load a file of your desired size and benchmark it.  Only then can you tell if you have a performance problem, as you will have measured it.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate an XPath expression that has variable references -- see **[XPathExpression.SetContext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4085db5.aspx)** and **[this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715.aspx)** how to implement an IXsltContextVariable.